# pygtk textview string formatting issue

Tags: python, string, formatting, pygtk

I have been trying to print python formatted string as tabular data in pygtk textview, but output goes wrong. however when copy the output from textview control to notepad or gedit, it shows as formated output. print on terminal is fine as well.

can you please guide me how can i do this?

```
'''
Created on Sep 12, 2015

@author: ibrahim
'''
data = [
        ('Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C', 'Columnd D', 'Column E'), 
        ('4', 'ABC', 'Title of product 1', 1.65, -2.4), 
        ('2.99', 'MDT', 'Title of product 1 is here', -0.16, -2.3968000000000003), 
        ('2.85', 'LLY', 'here is another title of another product', 1.19, -1.4985000000000002), 
        ('2.77', 'ABBV', 'Google.com', -0.39, -1.4652000000000003), 
        ('2.71', 'CELG', 'Corporation work', 0.81, -1.1988), 
        ('2.66', 'MCK', 'not working examle', 1.3, -1.0803), 
        ('2.53', 'BIIB', 'I am stuck here', 0.88, -0.9177), 
        ('2.49', 'ABT', 'Abbott Laboratories', 0.67, -0.6596000000000001), 
        ('2.41', 'BMY', 'Steel Mills Company', 0.8, -0.5712)]


from tabulate import tabulate

print tabulate(data[1:], data[0],tablefmt='orgtbl')


import sys

try:  
    import pygtk  
    pygtk.require("2.0")  
except:  
    pass  

try:  
    import gtk  
except:  
    print("GTK Not Availible")
    sys.exit(1)


class MyClass(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def __init__(self, builder):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.builder = builder
        builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window  = builder.get_object('window1')
        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()

        self.addRowToTextArea(tabulate(data[1:], headers=data[0], tablefmt='orgtbl'))

    def addRowToTextArea(self, text):
        position = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
        text += '\n'
        self.textbuffer.insert(position, text)

    def show_all(self):
        self.window.show_all()

    @property
    def textview(self):
        return self.builder.get_object("textview")

    def on_window1_destroy(self, *args):
        print "exiting application!"
        gtk.main_quit()

def run():
    builder = gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file("ui.glade")
    sm = MyClass(builder)
    sm.show_all()

    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

***ui.glade*** file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Example</property>
    <property name="window_position">center-always</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window1_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="fixed1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
            <property name="width_request">470</property>
            <property name="height_request">380</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="hscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
            <property name="vscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTextView" id="textview">
                <property name="width_request">300</property>
                <property name="height_request">380</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="border_width">5</property>
                <property name="editable">False</property>
                <property name="wrap_mode">word</property>
                <property name="justification">fill</property>
                <property name="right_margin">20</property>
                <property name="cursor_visible">False</property>
                <property name="accepts_tab">False</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">64</property>
            <property name="y">135</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label7">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">530</property>
            <property name="y">246</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Are you using a proportional font in the textview? Are you setting the tab stops in the textview, or are you using the default tab stops? You should post a [MCVE]: it's almost impossible to debug code we can't see.

Comment: As elya5 says, rather than using a simple TextView for this it's _much_ better to use a widget that's designed to handle tables. True, there's a bit of a learning curve, but the [Tree View tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html) is pretty good, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *PM 2Ring* already suspected in the comments, you are using a proportional font. Simply importing pango and adding `self.textview.modify_font(pango.FontDescription('monospace'))` in your init method should work.

However, you should note that your textview is too small to show the table nicely and for displaying data like this a GtkListView in combination with a GtkTreeStore is better suited.